# Can one export a crystal report in ".txt" format, by using Crystal Reports interface/software?

Tags: export, crystal-reports

I have crystal reports 2008, which allows to export reports in word (rtf), excel and pdf formats.
Is it possible to export a crystal report in text format?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the [Official Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=jsjxefAyLMsC&pg=PA441&lpg=PA441&dq=crystal+reports+2008+export+text) seems to suggest it's possible.

Comment: This seeps to be true as from the Official Guide, but there is no option in the Crystal Reports Viewer 2008 to export reports in text format.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Crystal Report 2008 (Version 12.1.0.892) without any additional add-ons or special extensions. 
The export dialog reached by the following tool bar icon

[image]

in my case lists an entry that is just names as "Text":
[image]

---

I apologize for using German screen shots. I have no English installation available.